# does "onplay" have a delay?

Tags: javascript, video, html5-video

When calling the `play()` function, I can see that there's a noticeable delay of 0.0~0.5 seconds before it actually starts playing.

I am facing some problems when using the following event listener

```
media.addEventListener(
    "play",
    function(){
        toggle_class(button[0], true);
        
        // compute animations for seekbar
        time_to_compute = media.duration - media.currentTime;
        progress.style = "transition: width linear " + time_to_compute + "s; width:100%;";
    }
);
```

Instead of changing the bar's position on time change, im changing it once and making it animated using a transition. The problem is that the transition starts BEFORE the video plays (0.0~0.5 seconds). This problem happens in both chrome and firefox.

Is there a javascript event for when the video **actually** plays?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`timeupdate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/timeupdate_event) event lets you know when the [`currentTime`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/currentTime) property changes, so you could wait to start the animation until the first `timeupdate` occurs. There's also the [`playing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/playing_event) event that fires when the media starts playing the first time or resumes playing after being paused, so you might be able to use that.

A full list of `HTMLMediaElement` events can be found [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement#events).

---

That said, I'd be very wary of an animation running in parallel with the video, they're **bound** to get out of sync. Instead, I'd probably use `timeupdate` with `requestAnimationFrame` to update the progress indicator.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But what do you mean by "bound" to get out of sync? Let's say the video plays with no buffering and no pauses for an hour, would the bar get out of sync then?

Comment: Also, making sure the time has changed when the play event has fired has fixed the issue for me. Many thanks!

Comment: edit: it doesnt work on chrome. the timeupdate event doesnt fire up when playback starts again